# My MayaVi screen has a big black border, how to solve it?

Tags: python, mayavi

[image]

As the picture shows, my MayaVi screen has a big black border.
If I select the option `Off screen rendering`, the whole dialog window is totally black,
Then I cancel this option, the MayaVi screen shows the correct result.

My OS is Archlinux, with a conda virtual environment.